# Django rest auth register user as an admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest auth and allauth to login and register users. I can register users by sending username, email, pwd1, pwd2. It is successful.

I am wondering, how can I register a user as an admin, do I need to send any extra parameter?

Comment: Do you mean superuser? superusers have all permissions.  I think what you need is a custom role, you can create a UserProfile model with the available roles or a custom User that will have a role field.